# Laravel URL issues for specific keywords

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am working on Laravel 4.2. I have create one route in route.php like 
    `abc.com/pro`.
    My Route For `abc.com/pro` is:

```
Route::get('pro', 'MyController@login');
```

Above URL working fine on local, but not working same on server.
Can anyone help me?
Does Laravel has some in built which does not allow Laravel itself in URI?

Comment: Can you show us your `routes.php` file? We can't help you if you don't show us your code.

Comment: please see route @Jerodev   Route::get('pro', 'MyController@login');

Comment: Can you please add public after abc.com, your url will be like below:
abc.com/public/pro please inform me wither it's works for you or not.

Comment: what does 'not working same on server' actually mean? an error? a 404 what?